Codemirror data overload and lagging problem
I am using the Codemirror version number is 5.44, and the React version is 16.13.1. There are about 200 lines of related code statements in the content area. When the code is only dozens of lines, it is not stuck. When the code is 200 lines, the deletion, addition, and modification statements are too laggy. The cursor will not come out until a few seconds later. What is the reason for this? I hope to get an answer!
I hope it won't get stuck even if there are multiple lines

I checked the code (written by someone else) and found that there is a chage event that executes every time, while the code in the change event is synchronous, blocking thread execution. Now, I have changed the change event to asynchronous and added 600ms of anti shake to solve this problem!
